# Wiring Repository interfaces in service layer dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The Service class and my repository classes in my spring MVC set up are something like this -

```
public class ObjectServiceImpl implements ObjectService {

@Autowired
Temp1Repo temp1Repo;
@Autowired
Temp2Repo temp2Repo;
...

}

public interface Temp1Repo extends CrudRepository<Temp1, Integer> {


}

public interface Temp2Repo extends CrudRepository<Temp2, Integer> {


}
```

Now, in my service class, i am getting a object of a type Temp1, I have to call temp1Repo.save(). If I get an object of Temp2, I have to call temp2Repo.save() and so on...

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems fairly simple to just have an if statement:

```
if(object instanceof Temp1) {
    temp1Repo.save((Temp1) object);
} else if(object instanceof Temp2) {
    temp2Repo.save((Temp2) object);
}
```

Or perhaps you are looking for a more generic way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to regroup all repositories in one. Something like

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class ObjectServiceImpl  {

    @Autowired
    private CrudRepository[] repositories;
    private Map<Class<?>, CrudRepository> repositoryMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, CrudRepository>();


     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
          for (CrudRepository r : repositories)
              repositoryMap.put(getType(r), r);
     }

    private Class<?> getType(CrudRepository repository) {

        Type[] types = repository.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
        for (Type t : types) {
            if (t instanceof ParameterizedType)
                return (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) t).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Check repositories...");
    }

    public void save(Object entity) {
        repositoryMap.get(entity.getClass()).save(entity);
    }

    public <T> T get(Object id, Class<T> clazz) {
        return repositoryMap.get(clazz).findOne(id);
    }

    ....

}
```

Consider to use `EntityManager` directly, but could be useful anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Following the code you wrote, Spring will rise an exception at startup time if any injection is missing.

What you want to do is a dynamic Module load, depending on a condition you omitted within your question.

You probably have to use XML configuration style and create a by condition spring context and load the correct one to be used.

Cheers